# How do I stop a build from running when I check in code?

Tags: azure-devops

In exploring devops I have set up several build pipelines for my Azure repository.

When I push my code the following pipeline runs
[image: first pipeline]

However I want to stop this pipeline running and run a different one instead.

[image: second pipeline]

Where do I configure this?

**[Update]**

From [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/ci-build-github?view=vsts)

It would appear to be to do with step 9, triggers.

[image: triggers]

How do I edit the triggers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the Triggers tab check Override YAML Continuous Integration trigger from here.
[image]

Then select Disable continuous integration
Than save